# Using Importdata to pull another googlesheet

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I'm trying to use importdata in one google sheet to pull data from another google sheet. I'm avoiding importrange because the file is used as a template and needs to be copied. reloading and re-allowing the data every time is time consuming and annoying.

The steps I currently take:

1. Take the data source sheet and "Publish to the web"
2. in the template sheet, `=query(importdata("<LINK of Datasource>", "Select Col1, Col2, Col3", 1)`

This returns the HTML code of the sheet instead of the data table. Is there a way to import the actual table from the data source sheet?

[image]

Comment: you can import actual table only with `IMPORTRANGE` fx

Comment: I still need to re-allow access everytime a copy is made when I use importrange. I want to avoid that.